# Diference between term and match in Elasticsearch in a bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple document where the _source looks like:

```json
{
    "name" : "myProduct",
    "label" : "isApiisApi",
    "isApi" : 1,
    "sold" : 0
}
```

I've been trying to create a multiple condition query using bool. The only way that I get it working was by using a match query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "sold": 0 } },
        { "term": { "isApi": 1 } },
        { "match": { "name": "myProduct" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But why doesn't it work when I use the term query (as the final condition):

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "sold": 0 } },
        { "term": { "isApi": 1 } },
        { "term": { "name": "myProduct" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what type of field is `name` in your index? kinda need to see the definition of the field to give a definitive answer

Comment: It a string type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Tldr;

Elastic [text fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) upon ingestion passes the data into a [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html).

By default the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is used. Which comes with a [token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenfilters.html) named [Lowercase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html).

Your text is indexed in lowercase.

But you are using a [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) which search for exact match on the indexed data.

In your case `myproduct` =/= `myProduct`.

## To Reproduce

By default Elastic index, all string like data in two fields.

- `text`
- `keyword`

For exact match you want to use the keyword version.

See below:

```json
POST /72020272/_doc
{
    "name" : "myProduct",
    "label" : "isApiisApi",
    "isApi" : 1,
    "sold" : 0
}

GET /72020272/_mapping

GET /72020272/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "sold": 0 } },
        { "term": { "isApi": 1 } },
        { "term": { "name": "myProduct" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET /72020272/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "sold": 0 } },
        { "term": { "isApi": 1 } },
        { "term": { "name.keyword": "myProduct" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it OK to use match in this case, along term for the others conditions?

Comment: It depends what is your aim. `match` is better suited for full text search, `terms` is best for exact match. Which seems to be your case so I would go with term. But once again I don't know the full story here ^^. The choice is yours to make

Comment: My name field will always be a single word that a I need to have an exact match. I tried using name.keyword but I didn't worked out :/, only with match

Comment: Make sure the mapping is correct.

Comment: it's a text field, looking at the documentation linked, they recommend using match for query for text field. Thank a lot for the explanation!