# wildcard and term search returning different results based on case

Tags: full-text-search, opensearch

I am using OpenSearch version 1.3.1 via the Docker image.

Here is my index and a document:

```json
PUT index_0
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "analyzer":{
            "keyword_lower":{
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"keyword",
               "filter":"lowercase"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "id":{
            "type":"text",
            "index":true
         },
         "name":{
            "type":"text",
            "index":true,
            "analyzer":"keyword_lower"
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT index_0/_doc/1
{
  "id":"123",
  "name":"FooBar"
}
```

If I run this query, I get results (notice the difference in case, lowercase b):

```json
GET index_0/_search?pretty
{"query":{"wildcard":{"name":"Foobar"}}}
```

But if I run this query, I do not:

```json
GET index_0/_search?pretty
{"query":{"term":{"name":"Foobar"}}}
```

Why does a `term` search seem to be case sensitive whereas a `wildcard` one is not, given the same field?

Comment: You should take a look a this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020272/diference-between-term-and-match-in-elasticsearch-in-a-bool-query/72020818#72020818

it is the same explanation

Comment: so a `wildcard` query is case insensitive by default? the documentation says there is a `case_insensitive` flag that is false by default: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: which version are you running ? tested myself on a 8.1 none return results

Comment: i am actually on opensearch 1.3.1. sorry, i will update my question to include that detail.